# Mail verification for firebase users not working correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

These are my codes, unfortunately I have no idea what I did wrong.

I have read and tried other articles but none of them helped me

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/compat/auth'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private fireauth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) { }
  
  // login method
  login(email: string, password: string) {
    this.fireauth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then( res => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', 'true');


      if (res.user?.emailVerified == true) {
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/verify-email']);
      }

    }, err => {
      alert(err.massage);
      this.router.navigate(['/firelogin']);
    })
  }

  //register method

  register(email: string, password: string) {
    this.fireauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then( res => {
      alert('Kayıt olma başarılı');
      this.router.navigate(['/firelogin']);
      this.sendEmailForVerification(res.user);
    }, err => {
      alert(err.message);
      this.router.navigate(['/register']);
    })
  }

  //sign out 
  logout() {
    this.fireauth.signOut().then(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      this.router.navigate(['/firelogin']);
    }, err => {
      alert(err.message);
    })
  }

  //forgot password
  
  forgotPassword(email: string) {
    this.fireauth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/verify-email']);
    }, err => {
      alert('Bir şeyler ters gitti');
    })
  }

  // email verify

  sendEmailForVerification(user : any) {
    user.sendEmailForVarification().then((res : any) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/verify-email']);
    }, (err: any) => {
      alert('Bir şeyler ters gitti, sizin mailinize link göndermek müsait değil')
    })
  }



}
```

I also tried with emails from temporary mail sites, but none of them worked.

What I'm trying to do is I want users to go through a mail verification stage as they go after registering their account

Comment: what do you do in the verify-email ts file, do you set emailVerfied field to true, once the successful verfication done and redirect to dashboard screen?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you said exactly, could you tell me what I should do with the codes and in detail?

Comment: 1. in your verify email ts file, you will call a function right on clicking the verify email button, in that function update the firebase user data with {emailVerfied : true},
2. incallback to the update call, redirect user to the /dashboard screen like this._router.navigate(['dashboard'])